# Send an email using Servcie Account >> but set reply to for another user

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

We have this scenario: -

1. we have a scheduled flow >> which send an email using

[image: johnjohn123_0-1682779409566.png]

to our clients >> and we need the clients to reply back and upload a certificate and send it to our project manager.

now the Send an email (V2) will run using a service account , but we need the users to reply and send the certificate to a specific user inside our project management team, so how we can achieve this? i do not want to use a connection created by the project manager because we have a policy to reset the users' accounts password each 40 days (unlike the service account which have no password reset) so we do not have to worry about updating the connections inside power automate whenever the password got reseted.. so what are the available options that we have?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to include the project manager's email address in the email body or subject, so that clients can manually address their reply to the project manager.

Another option could be to create a shared mailbox or distribution list that includes the project manager's email address, and configure the flow to send emails from the shared mailbox or distribution list instead of the service account.
This way, clients can reply to the shared mailbox or distribution list, and the project manager will receive the email.

Another option could be to use a third-party service such as Microsoft Power Automate Approvals, which allows users to approve or reject requests through email, and configure the flow to send the certificate as an approval request to the project manager.